# What's wrong with this e-mail validator expression?

Tags: regex, validation

A contact form on a website rejected an email address I've been using for years.  I assumed it was because my TLD is `.Email`, so I put the real address in the body and put `Wrong.Address@Nowhere.com` in the field.  Still claimed invalid.  Made it all lower case.  Still claimed invalid.  Removed the period.  Still rejected.  Examined their source code, but it looks to me like it should have accepted everything I tried except the first (which has five characters in the TLD).

```html
<input id='Textbox-2'
       data-sf-role="text-field-input"
       type="email"
       name="TextFieldController_0"
       placeholder="Email"
       value=""
       pattern=\A[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4}\z
       class="form-control" />
```

(I added the line breaks to save y'all from lots of horizontal scrolling).  Why is the pattern failing?  Could it be the failure to surround it with quote marks?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4}"`?

Comment: If I knew, I wouldn't have asked.  If you think that's it, why not write an answer instead of asking a question in a comment?

Comment: I ask because I am not sure if the code is handled in a "usual" way. If it is HTML5 engine that handles the `pattern` regex, then it is clear you need to remove `\A` and `\z`, or is there any Ruby engine behind it? Why use `\A` and `\z`?

Comment: Not clear to me.  Is Ruby able to modify the definition of HTML?  If these guys don't know that MANY TLDs have been more than four characters long for years, I suspect they also don't know how to use Ruby.

Comment: Well, I have seen scenarios when the `pattern` was overridden and was processed in an unusual way, that is why I am asking. If HTML5 is in play, the answer is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\A` and `\z` are anchors (start of string and end of string repspectively) that are not supported by JS regex flavor where `^` and `$` are used. However, the [HTML5 `pattern`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-pattern-attribute) regex is processed with HTML5 engine that wraps the pattern with `^(?:` and `)$`, thus, anchoring the pattern by default.

You should make sure `\A` and `\z` are removed from the pattern:

```
pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4}"
```

Comment: I can't change it; it's not my form.  And since the purpose of the form is to prevent revealing their email address, I can't tell them they screwed up.  I only asked here because I couldn't see an error.